# rails - adding a validation if user is a guest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have created an appointment apps that allows users to login via guest, but I need to have them put in theircontact number before creating an appointment. Can't seem to find a way to do this because I can't access currentl signed in users credentials in appointment model for validation. Any help on what approach should I do?

Comment: You can use attr_accessor and validate it.

Answer (score 0):

May be smth like this:

```
validates :contact_number, presence: true, if: :current_user.guest?
```